# What does "as it stands" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms

I searched in dictionary and it returned "in its present condition". Here is the corresponding example:

> the country would struggle, as it stands, to host the next World Cup

Can I simply replace it with "now"? More examples will be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"[Hosting] the next World Cup" cannot happen until sometime in the future.

In this context, "as it stands" is subtly different from "now".

"As it stands" means "if things continue the way they are now", or "if things don't change from the way they are now".

Comment: Jasper, I am impressed. You have explained the meaning of the phrase "as it stands" in a better way. +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

Whereas "now" is simply a divider between past and present - a time notion, "as it stands" encompasses a physical/cultural/business state which is typically expected to require proactive input to change vs simply the passing of time (eg reduce costs, deal with corruption etc).

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic phrase "as it stands" means "in its present condition" as the OP has mentioned. In other words, we may say that it means "as it's now, without any changes to it".

This plan as it stands is not practicable.

We have no option but to accept the proposal as it stands.

I don't think we can change the phrase "as it stands" to "as it's now" as the former  is more idiomatic, meaningful,  and sounds good.